# Problema al enviar array del controlador al modelo

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un problema al enviar un `array` que contiene los datos de un formulario del `contralodor` al `modelo`, cuando los datos llegan a la base de datos llegan `NULL`, he revisado el código, he buscado en Internet y no encuentro que esta mal...

**CONTROLADOR**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pacientes extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Pacientes_model');

    }

    public function guardar() {
        $datos_paciente = array(
            'cod_tii_paciente' => $this->input->post('sel_ti'),
            'no_ide_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_nro_ide'),
            'nom1_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_nom1'),
            'nom2_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_nom2'),
            'ape1_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_ape1'),
            'ape2_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_ape2'),
            'sexo_paciente' => $this->input->post('sel_sexo'),
            'fec_nac_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_fec_nac'),
            'cod_est_civ_paciente' => $this->input->post('sel_ec'),
            'cod_ocup_paciente' => $this->input->post('text_ocup'));

        $this->Pacientes_model->insertar($datos_paciente);


    }

}
```

**MODELO**

```
<?php

class Pacientes_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function insertar($datos_paciente){
        $this->db->insert('pacientes',$datos_paciente);
    }


}
```

ESTA ES LA VISTA:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Ingreso de Pacientes</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                        <div class=”panel panel-defaul”> 
                             <div class=”row”>  
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Tipo de Identificacion</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <select name="sel_ti" class="form-control control-label" id="sel_ti">
                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($consulta_ti as $i) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $i->cod_ti_ide . '">' . ucwords($i->nom_ti_ide) . '</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Numero de Indetificacion</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="text_nro_ide" id="text_nro_ide">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>

                        <div class=”row”>  
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label" name="nombre">Primer Nombre</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_nom1" id="text_nom1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Segundo Nombre</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_nom2" id="text_nom2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class=”row”>  
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Primer Apellido</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_ape1" id="text_ape1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Segundo Apellido</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_ape2" id="text_ape2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class=”row”>  
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Sexo</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <select class="form-control control-label" id="sel_sexo" name="sel_sexo">
                                        <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                                        <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input  type="date" class="form-control" id="text_fec_nac" name="text_fec_nac">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class=”row”>  
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Estado Civil</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <select class="form-control control-label" id="sel_ec" name="sel_ec">
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($consulta_ec as $i) {
                                            echo '<option value="' . $i->cod_est_civil . '">' . ucwords($i->desc_est_civil) . '</option>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Ocupacion</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_ocup" id="text_ocup">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class=”row”>  
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Direccion</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_dir" id="text_dir">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Telefono Fijo</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input class="form-control"  name="text_tel" id="text_tel">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                     <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
                                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <button type="button" id="btn_enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/pacientes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EL archivo JS contiene:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_enviar").click(function () {
        //   alert ('hola');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/gestiontotweb/pacientes/guardar',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (msj) {
                alert(msj);
                //    $("#mensaje").html(msj);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

database config:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => '********',
    'database' => 'GESTIONCLINICA',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Hola ganedugo, coloca también el código de la vista donde tienes tu formulario, para poder ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: Hola Juan...cuando agrego en el models el codigo que me sugeriste me da como resulatdo esto: 35Array ( [cod_tii_paciente] => [no_ide_paciente] => [nom1_paciente] => [nom2_paciente] => [ape1_paciente] => [ape2_paciente] => [sexo_paciente] => [fec_nac_paciente] => [cod_est_civ_paciente] => [cod_ocup_paciente] => )

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta prueba, eso a ver si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has iniciado la conexión a la base de datos, al momento de crear tu modelo CodeIgniter no inicializa la conexión a la db automáticamente, por lo que tienes que hacer manualmente.

Tu modelo esta actualmente asi:

```
class Pacientes_model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }


  public function insertar($datos_paciente){
    $this->db->insert('pacientes',$datos_paciente);
  }
}
```

Para inicializar la conexión con la base de datos deberías tener algo así

```
class Pacientes_model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database(); //Aquí inicializas la conexión
  }


  public function insertar($datos_paciente){
    $this->db->insert('pacientes',$datos_paciente);
  }
}
```

Suponiendo que la configuración de la base de datos esta correcta debería guardarte correctamente.

Algo adicional es que tambien deberías comprobar con un if si se inserto datos correctamente, ya que si lo dejas asi como esta no tendras una manera de saber que retorno el insert, para esto podrías hacer algo así:

```
  public function insertar($datos_paciente){
    if($this->db->insert('pacientes',$datos_paciente)){
      return $this->db->insert_id(); //Para obtener el ultimo id insertado de la tabla pacientes
    }else{
      return $this->db->error();
    }
  }
```

En tu llamada ajax intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost/gestiontotweb/pacientes/guardar',
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { 'sel_ti': $('sel_ti').val(),
                 'text_nro_ide': $('text_nro_ide').val()
               },
         success: function (msj) {
            alert(msj);
            //    $("#mensaje").html(msj);
         }
       });
```

Luego haz un print_r($datos_paciente); en tu controlador para ver si te esta llegando la información a través de ajax.

Comment: Según leo, se expone que la data si llega , si fuera error de conexión no llegaría quizá

Comment: Ya publique el resto del codigo

Comment: No funcionó inicializando la base de datos?

Comment: Hola Juan....bueno te comento de que despues de darle por completo,  he consiguido que guarde los datos en la base de datos, el problema radica en que no lo hace siempre, alguna veces otras veces no y la verdad no comprendo por ocurre esto, el error que me muestra cuando no guarda es el siguinte:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::_error_message() in

Answer (score 0):

Revisa por pasos.
En tu ajax agrega

**beforeSend:function(){console.log($('#form').serialize());},**

para que visualices si estas enviando datos.(en lo personal me da mucho problema el **form.serialize();**)

Cuando llegua a tu controlador antes de enviar a la DB, has un
      **print_r($datos_paciente);**

y cachalos en en 
**success:function(data){console.log(data);},** 
Asi compruebas que esta enviando datos y reciviendo.

Antes guardar en la db, es decir el el modelo has un return de tu array para que compruebes que estas enviando datos y imprimelos con un 
 
**var_dump($array);**

Con esta funcion sabes que tipo de varaibles vas a guardar.
Activa el el **$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);** de CI
Asi ves el insert y visualizas que tipo de variables estas ingresando en que tipo de campo.

Por lo regular me falla al enviar el dato en el ajax o al ingresar los datos en la db, por la configuracion de la tabla, si tienes datos como not null y no ingresas nada no te guarda el registro no das el formato adecuado a la fecha